# Catching hell with if's in php?

Tags: php

ok forgive my technique in writing here, but i can't seem to understand why this code recognizes things and then doesn't recognize some other things.

my code:

```
if (!isset($id)) {
      $_SESSION["logged_in"] = False;
      printf("Could not retrieve records: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
     if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] = False)
        { echo "session variable is set at False"; }
     if ( $_SESSION["logged_in"] = True)
        { echo "session variable is set at True"; }
  }
```

now as I see it, if it enters this bit of code at all, the first thing that happens should be that the variable gets set to "false". elsewhere in some code not shown it gets set to true and that part works fine but when i try to force it into this for a false setting it remains true.. can anyone see why this wouldn't get set to "False" at this point in the execution?

Comment: Please revisit some of your previous questions and accept answers where appropriate. You'll get more and swifter help in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need == or ===

Using = means its equal :)

```
if (!isset($id)) {
      $_SESSION["logged_in"] = False;
      printf("Could not retrieve records: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
     if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] == False)
        { echo "session variable is set at False"; }
     if ( $_SESSION["logged_in"] == True)
        { echo "session variable is set at True"; }
  }
```

Comment: Using `=` doesn't mean "it's equal". It means _is assigned the value of_

Comment: Hah, your right. Just typed the same mistake as the OP - ironic :&

Answer (score 7):

You should be using `==` for comparison here, not `=` for assignment:

```
if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] = False)
//         ---------------^^^
// Should be
if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] == False)

// Also here:
if ( $_SESSION["logged_in"] = True)
//--------------------------^^
// Should be
if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] == True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a classic mistake by assigning the variable in your if statement instead of comparing it. So, change your if statements to:

```
if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] == false)
```

Instead of (where you are assigning):

```
if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] = false)
```

By the way, you're statement has now some duplication since the variable itself already is true of false. So, there is no need to check it against the boolean. So, this can be enough:

```
if ($_SESSION["logged_in"])  //equals true if user is logged in
if (!$_SESSION["logged_in"])  // equals true if user is NOT logged in
```

Comment: Classic, but oh so annoying :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the  `==` operator rather than `=` in your if statements.

EG

`if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] == False)`